# How can I run pam_cracklib from command line?

Tags: linux, unix

There is a standard linux library pam_cracklib.so which allows to set up checks for passwords users choose. But how can I just run pam_cracklib.so from command line just to see whether a password will be accepted or rejected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cracklib-check` program for that. It simply takes passwords from `stdin` and outputs error/success messages to `stdout`.

Few examples:

```
$ cracklib-check
Hello
Hello: it is too short.
```

```
$ cracklib-check
He4 X/%/32?+llo
He4 X/%/32?+llo: OK.
```

```
$ echo "He4 X/%/32?+llo" | cracklib-check
He4 X/%/32?+llo: OK.
```

Comment: It accepts passwords such as nicegrape, tapitout, peachgrape, peachcobbler. Shouldn't dictionary check look for concatenated words?

Comment: @BabuSrinivasan See http://thegarywilson.com/blog/2006/using-cracklib-to-require-stronger-passwords/ for cracklib configuration or maybe google for it. It depends on how you are using it / what extensions are installed for cracklib to use.